# Checking apache is running

Tags: python, apache

I want to write a function which print everything is fine when apache is running, so I decided to count the number of process which are using apache, and it is 8. So I want to print apache is running when it has more than 2 process.
So v is 8 but still not working, so I decided to convert into a string, but still not solved the problem.

Do you have any idea why it's not working?
""""

```
import os
def checkApacheStatus():
    v = os.system("ps -ef| awk '{print $1}'|grep apache|wc -l")
    p = int(v)
    if p>2:
        print("apache is running")
```

""""
checkApacheStatus()

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` does not return the output of the command.  It simply returns the success code, a number from 0 o 255.  You'll need to use subprocess.

```
import subprocess
v = subprocess.Popen("ps -ef|awk '{print $1}'|grep apache|wc -l",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p = int(v.stdout.read())
```

Note that "grep -c" can give you a count of found lines directly.